# In C, is 'int *' a derived datatype?

Tags: c, pointers, types, declaration

Is `int *` a derived datatype or not?

I got this confusion because I feel that these two cases are contradicting in regard to this question.

---

**case 1:**
**Assumption:** `int *` is to be considered as a derived datatype. then considering this below given code -

```
void someRandomFunction()
{
    int* a, b, c, d;
    int  e, f, g, h;
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

In this function, if we need to consider `int *` as a derived datatype, then just like `e, f, g, h` are variables of `int` datatype,  all the variables `a, b, c, d` must be pointers pointing to `int` datatype, right?

But since it is only `a` which is a pointer pointing to `int` datatype, so does this **disprove our assumption** of this case?

---

**Case 2:**
**Assumption:** `int *` is **not** to be considered as a derived datatype. then considering this below given code -

```
int* MyFunc()
{
    int *p;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    return p;
}
```

Here, `int *` is instructing the `return's datatype` to the compiler, right? So, Does this prove that `int *` is a derived datatype, i.e., does this **disprove our assumption** of this case?

Comment: What do you mean by derived datatype?

Comment: b,c,d,e,f,g,h are not pointers to int. The identifier 'b' for example is a direct translation to the adress of the int variable. While the identifier 'a' is a direct translation to the adress which holds an adress to an int variable. A subtle difference.

Comment: Any property of `b` does not mean anything whether `int*` is a derived data type or not (whatever you mean by that) as `b` is not of type `int` at all. You cannot deduct any property about X from objects that are not X.

Comment: I have a hard time  understanding how you reason. I was almost with you all the way when you reasoned about "yes,  it's a derived datatype" but you lost me at the end.

Comment: I never heard about the concept of derived data types but a simple google search says all pointers are derived data types https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/c-program/c-derived-and-user-defined-data-types.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C and derived data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025465/c-and-derived-data-types)

Comment: @kiner_shah I just saw an answer where someone has mentioned that there are 3 types of datatypes in c - Basic, Derived and user-defined. I'm not 100 percent sure about their definitions so I don't know whether I can ask whether 'int *' is a **derived datatype** or not. But is 'int *' still a datatype (no matter which classification does it belongs to among the Basic, Derived and User-defined)?

Comment: As per [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), in section 6.2.5 point number 20, a pointer type is a derived type. `int*` is a pointer to `int` so, yeah it seems like it is a derived type.

Answer (score 1):

> Is int * a derived datatype or not?

It is a derived type from the object type `int`.

> if we need to consider int * as a derived datatype, then just like e,
> f, g, h are variables of int datatype, all the variables a, b, c, d
> must be pointers pointing to int datatype, right?

If you will introduce the type `int *` as a type specifier as for example

```
typedef int * T;
```

then indeed in this declaration

```
T a, b, c, d;
```

all the declared variables have the type `int *`. Otherwise the symbol `*` is related to the declarator of the variable `a` in this declaration

```
int* a, b, c, d;
```

that may be rewritten like

```
int ( * a ), b, c, d;
```

Pay attention to that declaration is defined like (here is a partial definition of declaration):

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;

declaration-specifiers:
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt

init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator

init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer
```

That is in this declaration

```
int* a, b, c, d;
```

the common type specifier of all declarators is `int` and the declarator `a` has the form `*a`.

While in this declaration

```
T a, b, c, d;
```

the common type specifier is `T` that represents the derived pointer type `int *`.

That is the derived pointer type int * is being built from its referenced type `int`.  The derived type `int **` is being built from its referenced type `int *` and so on.

So for example passing by reference in C means passing an object indirectly through another object of its derived pointer type that references the type of the original object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.
We have an fundamental datatypes (int, float, double,...) and we have an derived
datatypes and we also have a derived datatypes(fundamental datatype with some
extensions).

In your first example `int* a, b, c, d;` we have an `a` as a pointer to integer
but `b, c, d` **are not pointers to the integers, because they are just integers** !

So, yes you are right! `int*` is derived from the int.
Your confusion has started with taking `b,c,d` also as a pointers but they are not.
In C programming language during the variable declaration process if there is an `*`
between variable name and hers datatype than that variable is a pointer to hers
datatype.

Answer (score 0):

A derived datatype is a datatype derived from a fundamental datatype. In this case, `int *` is a derived datatype from `int`.

Your first analysis is incorrect. Getting `b, c, d` to have `int` datatype doesn't say that `int *` is not a derived datatype. So It's just about how C is working. that's why it's always a good idea to write the declaration like that: `int *a, ....` so the `*` is adjacent to the variable, not the type to signalize that any coming variables don't take the `*` but only the datatype.

Just like the array.

```
int a[10], b;
```

here the array is a derived datatype but `b` has type `int` doesn't also suggest the array is not a derived datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays, structures, unions, functions, pointers, and atomic types are derived from other types.

`int* a, b;` is not a way of expressing that `b` is a pointer type. The grammar of the declaration is such that `*` binds with `a`; the declaration is actually `int *a, b;`, as if it were `int *a; int b;`.

In C, declarations use a basic type, like `int`, and then describe derived types by using [a “picture” of how the type will be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077428/298225). In `int *a;`, we are saying that `*a` will be used as an `int`. From this, it is deduced that `a` must be a pointer to an `int`. Similarly, `int *a[3]` says that `*a[i]` will be used as an `int`, so `a[i]` must be a pointer to an `int`, so `a` must be an array of pointers to `int`.

Then `int *a, b;` says `*a` is an `int` and `b` is an `int`.